# jquery getJSON works in PHP file but not HTML file

Tags: php, jquery, html, getjson

I'm trying to use getJSON in an HTML. This works in a PHP file, but not HTML. I've tried get and ajax and haven't gotten any closer.

The json file checks as valid at jsonlint.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.getJSON("userlist.json", function(data) {
            return localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(data));
        });          

    })    
</script>
```

Comment: Are you definitely including jQuery in the HTML file, before that script?  The problem doesn't lie with the JS above or the JSON.  There's something different about the PHP and HTML files - you need to figure out what that is.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in the snippet. So, what debugging have you performed? Are any errors being reported in your browser's developer tools? Have you tried adding a [`.fail()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) (or `error`) callback to get details? Are the JSON and HTML files in the same directory? Are they being requested with HTTP?

Comment: @Archer -- yep. network in Chrome Dev tools show jQuery is loaded.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski -- Here's the error I get. I'm not sure what to do.  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/charliemagee/Sites/gg-firebase/userlist.json. Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @charliemagee Ajax is generally not allowed with `file://` as they don't have an origin (`Origin 'null'`) to validate against. Some browsers have options to enable it, but it's typically easier to use `http://`, even for `.html`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski -- ah, sorry to be so lame. I've heard of that but never run into it before. Would you mind giving me an example of how to force it to use http in my test environment? I use MAMP for my PHP files and all works well. Not sure how to do it here.

Comment: if you open your html file from your MAMP server, it should work fine, rather than opening things directly from a file folder. Whatever the url is you're using to open the file as a php file, lop off the .php and add .html (saving the html file in the appropriate spot) should do it

Comment: np.  @JonathanLonowski did most of the leg work.  Hi-fives all around for a job well done, team!

Comment: Yes, thanks much for helping with something I should have known but got away with for a while. Much thanks.